# Special characters in MySql Password

Tags: mysql, function, validation, passwords

Our app continues to have problem with MySql passwords.  We would like to create a function to test for password validity before it is presented to the database.

Can anyone direct me to guidelines for MySql passwords involving these 2 topics:

1. password max length  (hash is stored as 16 bit varchar which does not mean 16 is max length)
2. which punctuation / special characters can be used in a MySql password?

Comment: There's no restriction on characters in the password. if you can squeeze the chars into an sql query, they'll work - remember that mysql stores a HASH of the password. the characters that composed the password are irrelevant once the hash is produced. As for the rest, RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 5.6.6 is the first release that has any password strength guidelines or enforcement.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password.html

But for what it's worth, there have never been any restrictions on the length of a password or characters supported. MySQL stores a hash of the password string, not the string itself, and hashes are always stored as a fixed length string of hexadecimal digits, not the plaintext password.

You aren't specific about what problems your app is having with MySQL passwords. Perhaps if you edit your question to describe these problems in more detail, you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: The mysql-doc link is broken

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have same problem in MySQL 8.0.26 (windows)
With this password for example `0fBéF81ù9·ìÔqr¥»üéça¾[!¡L£_@+À³ù` change password is OK. But after that login is denied. If I try another with normal alphanumeric everything OK. That is curios because the same password work in linux but not in windows

Comment: @BillKarwin I have tried also: password = `e` is ok, password = `é` NOT WORK (change pass ok but denied at login ... directly on console )

Comment: MySQL does not store hash of password string. MySQL stores hash of password *bytes*, and those bytes come in whatever character encoding they happen to be.  The cli defaults to console charset, something from DOS times, however if password is passed as command line parameter, rather than entered interactively --password=<string>, cli will convert that to UTF8 , and that's likely the bug @MTK

Answer (score 11):

I'm using MariaDB 10.0.13 - the '\' character is a bit special.
If defining a password using PASSWORD('text'), make sure to escape use of '\'.

Example:
set password for user@localhost = PASSWORD('\\');

You can then use a single '\' for the password with mysql:
mysql -u user --password='\'

Comment: Apparently, MySQL 14.14 has the same issue. I couldn't log in after creating a password containing a backslash character. Apparently, the character was interpreted as an escape character and missing from the output password. Typing the password without the backslash character allowed me to successfully log in.

Comment: Hah, thanks for this, I used a random password and didn't notice the backslash, feel dumb now.

Answer (score -2):

As per [this mail list](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/67001), by default password length is 16 characters but you can change it by alter table command.

For special characters there is no specific documentation about allowed password characters. but on this link it is written that all of the ASCII characters are allowed for password. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-names.html